# How can I search for a specific string in a object array?

Tags: java, arrays

I need write a method that searches an object array of Club Members for a specific member and returns true if the member is found. This is what I have now.

```
 public boolean isMember (String name){
    boolean found = false;
    int arrayIndex = 0;
    while(arrayIndex < members.length && !found){
        if(members[arrayIndex] == name){
            found = true;
        }
        arrayIndex++;
    }
    return found;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `==` to compare String values. Use `equals()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java, strings can only be compared with the .equals method, not with ==.

You can change your if condition like this:

```
 if(members[arrayIndex].equals(name))
```

Comment: It's not correct at all, `String`s can also be compared with `==`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 found = Arrays.asList(members).contains(name)
```